# Add data to a string of html with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a string of html that I get via `$("#datadiv").html();`. Within this data are several other elements, and what I would like to do is append some data to one of those elements.

e.g.

```
var data = $("#datadiv").html();
var somestring = "Some text"
```

then append somestring into the div #stringholder inside of data. Is this possible?

And before the question comes, no I can't add it to the div before doing `$("#datadiv").html();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$(data).find("#stringholder").append(somestring);
```

As the [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method returns a string, you need to pass it into jQuery again to create a jQuery object. You can then call [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get the element you want, and [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to append the other string.

jQuery is quite happy to accept a string of [HTML as an argument](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2). It's not just selector strings that are accepted. If you pass in a string of HTML, that fragment will be the context for further method calls.

I think you already know this, but note that this will not affect the HTML in the DOM. It will only affect the fragment produced by passing the string into jQuery.

Comment: This seems to have worked as expected, but now I'm having the problem of assigning the data back to a variable. I tried `data = $(data).find("#wysiwygIFrame").append(somedata)`, but that just assigns the JQuery function to the variable. I also tied `data = $(data).find("#wysiwygIFrame").append(somedata).html();`, but that doesn't work as I would expect it. So, any tips on that?

Comment: Your second attempt looks about right. See a small example here: http://jsfiddle.net/QbRgt/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean :

```
var data = $("#datadiv").html();
var somestring = "Some text"
var newData = data + " " + somestring;
var holderData = $("#stringholder").html();
var newestData = holderData + " " + newData;
$("#stringholder").html('');
$("#stringholder").html(newestData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure.   Basically you could dump the string from the current div in to a variable and then concate the additional text and put it back in the div.

```
var someText = $('#datadiv').html()
var someNewText = 'my new text'
var someText = someText + ' ' + someNewText
$('#datadiv').html('') //this will clear the current text but not really necessary.
$('#datadiv').html('someText')
```

you just need to have some event that fires to trigger everything.